# Android View subclass java.lang.RuntimeException: view tag isn't correct on view:null

Tags: android, xml, binding, runtime-error, android-custom-view

I'm getting an error when I try to use my subclassed RelativeLayout when I also have databinding. My goal is to have a subclassed view that also has databinding as part of it. If what I'm doing is wrong, is there another way I can do this? When I run the app, everything is fine by the preview gives off this error when trying to render.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: view tag isn't correct on view:null
```

My XML layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_ttl_first_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="First Name:"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_first_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="First Name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/tv_ttl_first_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_ttl_first_name"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

And I have a subclass of Relative layout which uses that XML:

```
public class ContainerSingleBabyInfo extends RelativeLayout {
    private static final String TAG = ContainerSingleBabyInfo.class.getSimpleName();
    protected ContainerSingleBabyInformationBinding binding;

    //region Overrides
    public ContainerSingleBabyInfo(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.init(context);
    }

    public ContainerSingleBabyInfo(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.init(context);
    }

    public ContainerSingleBabyInfo(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater inflater =  LayoutInflater.from(context);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.container_single_baby_information, this, true);
    }
}
```

And here of the snippet of my using my class:

```
<com.foo.bar.Views.InfoContainers.ContainerSingleBabyInfo
    android:id="@+id/vw_single_baby_info"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/vw_icons"
    android:layout_above="@+id/vw_fresh_btn_container"
    android:visibility="visible"
    layout="@layout/container_single_baby_information"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - view tag isn't correct on view:null (CursorAdapter and DataBinding)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33116688/android-view-tag-isnt-correct-on-viewnull-cursoradapter-and-databinding)

Comment: The solution didn't work for me.