# Why am I getting a Java.lang.RuntimeException: view tag isn't correct on view:null

Tags: java, android, adapter

I have, below, a RecyclerView.Adapter. The Adapter works fine without ItemDiscussionListHeaderBinding, but once that is added in, with the two viewtypes, I got an Java.lang.RuntimeException: view tag isn't correct on view:null. Why is this the case?

Inside my Adapter.java:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    switch (viewType) {
        case BODY:
            ItemDiscussionListBodyBinding bodyBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.item_discussion_list_body, parent, false);
            return new DiscussionListItemBodyViewHolder(bodyBinding);
        case HEADER:
            ItemDiscussionListHeaderBinding headerBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.item_discussion_list_header, parent, false);
            return new DiscussionListItemHeaderViewHolder(headerBinding);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Discussion discussion = mDiscussions.get(position);
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case BODY:
            ((DiscussionListItemBodyViewHolder) holder).bind(discussion);
            break;
        case HEADER:
            ((DiscussionListItemHeaderViewHolder) holder).setHeader("My Discussions");
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDiscussions.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return HEADER;
    }
    return BODY;
}
```

Inside my two viewholders:

```
class DiscussionListItemBodyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ItemDiscussionListBodyBinding mBinding;

    DiscussionListItemBodyViewHolder(ItemDiscussionListBodyBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        mBinding = binding;
    }

    void bind(Discussion discussion) { // do whatever }


class DiscussionListItemHeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ItemDiscussionListHeaderBinding mBinding;

    DiscussionListItemHeaderViewHolder(ItemDiscussionListHeaderBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        mBinding = binding;
    }

    void setHeader(String header) { // do whatever }
```

I have narrowed the error down to the header binding, not the body binding, and here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/lighter_gray"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="14dp"
    android:paddingRight="14dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_discussion_list_header_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Classes" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - view tag isn't correct on view:null (CursorAdapter and DataBinding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33116688/android-view-tag-isnt-correct-on-viewnull-cursoradapter-and-databinding)

Comment: I saw that post, it shouldn't be because 1) mine involves 2 bindings thus two view holders

Comment: So? It's still the same issue. *I have a problem adding two integers, but it's not the same because mine has four variables declared and the other only had two*? If the problem is happening when you add the second one, then you should be looking at the second one.

Comment: That solution, inside bind() method it calls DataBindingUtil.getBinding(view), whereas my method only passes a holder inside bind(), how would I use getBinding